# what kind of algorithm do I need to solve the wood blocks jigsaw game?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I'm writing a computer program to solve the wood blocks jigsaw game. Do you guys know which computer algorithm do I need? In this game: blocks with different shapes has to fit with each other in 2D window - without leaving paces below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the exact rules of the game. If you know all the pieces in advance and you can choose their order as well, then you can implement a custom algorithm, which would first plan matching the pieces and then match the matches until the whole plan is figured out.

If you know what the pieces and you know their order, but you cannot control their order, then you can do some backtracking calculation for the future events.

If you do know what the pieces are, but you do not know their order, then you can backtrack all the separate cases in a similar fashion as above.

If you do not know what the pieces are, nor their order, then you will need to define a heuristic, which would be a probabilistic value that you will be able to correctly place the next item and compute possible variations in a very similar fashion as the alpha-beta pruning known in chess computation.

By the way, if you do a backtracking approach, then you can still use a heuristic and pruning.

Comment: Note that although it's rare, some particularly devious puzzles are designed so that various pieces may fit together pair-wise, but not quite fit when assembled as a group.  As a simple example, some pieces which seem like they could go in one row might have connecting bits that force their spacing to be in the range 1.90cm to 1.98cm, while those which seem like they could go in the next row might have prongs that limit their spacing to the range 2.02cm to 2.10cm, all while connections between the rows have 0.8mm of slop.  A few pieces could fit together...

Comment: ...under such circumstances, but if the rows are too long, the difference in spacing would exceed the slop of the interconnecting pieces.

Comment: @supercat thanks for pointing that out. It is good then to take this into account when we do an actual implementation and add row-checking to the heuristics.

Comment: @LajosArpad: If each possible pair of edges can be straightforwardly classified as either fitting or not fitting, without regard for connections involving non-adjacent pieces, one can use much simpler algorithms than if one needs to accommodate pieces which are deliberately cut with enough "slop" that their fit may be controlled by the presence of non-adjacent pieces.  A 100,000-piece puzzle with easily discernible edge relations may be easily solvable in under a second, while a 100-piece puzzle that's sufficiently devious might be almost impossible to solve in any reasonable time.

Comment: I know the pieces in advance and I can also chose their order. The problem lies in the huge number of the search space. To solve the puzzle, I need to match 20 blocks, each could have one of 4 different shapes. This brings 10 to power 12 options to chose from... The next question is how can I reduce this number?

Comment: @Joku the problem-space can always be reduced by utilizing a pattern to your advantage. Creating a heuristic on the basis of a pattern you recognize and then utilizing that pattern to prune fairly large branches from the search tree can help you greatly.

Comment: @LajosArpad what is the difference when the player got the whole puzzle mixed up and wanted to reorder it, without adding or removing any blocks, like in Rubik's Cube?

Comment: @Joku If we do an abstraction, then nothing. Let me elaborate. We can ignore that we are not adding/removing pieces, but reordering them, by saying that we make a move. For instance, at checkers you add pieces to the tables, but in chess (with the exception of pawn promotion or piece capturing) you are reorganizing them. In both cases you make a move. In Rubik's cube you can also distribute your actions into atomic "moves". However, whether your move is reversible or irreversible, that makes a huge difference, because then you no longer have a game tree.

Comment: @Joku in Rubik's cube your moves are reversible, but in checkers your moves are irreversible. So, in checkers you can perfectly analyze the situation using a game tree, while in Rubik's cube you can encounter cycles, which are obvious patterns to prune in order to reach a game tree.